# Jenkins: how can I add -D parameter to the build?

Tags: jenkins

How can i make Jenkins do the following:

When i create a WAR file i normally run the following command:

```
mvn clean install -Dapp.env=SOME_ENVIRONMENT
```

Which loads the specific properties for that environment. I've added a build parameter in Jenkins, but this has had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a new job or modifying an existing job you can put this directly into Goals and options under 'Build':

```
clean install -Dapp.env=SOME_ENVIRONMENT
```